# detect HTTP method name in module.php of zend after exception has thrown

Tags: php, http, exception, module, zend-framework2

I need to detect the HTTP method name from module.php file. For this i have tried following code which only gives me GET method,

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
$getRequest = new Request();
$httpMethod=$getRequest->getMethod();
```

But in $httpMethod variable i am only getting GET as method name. I am handling errors so in a way i need to detect the which method is being called by my REST Api. Is there any solution for this so i can detect PUT,POST and DELETE method also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vanilla PHP;

```
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Comment: do you know how we can achieve this same through zend framework 2

Comment: I have no experience with Zend, so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: thanks anyway and np for that. I know how to receive GET and POST parameters, need to know about PUT and DELETE tech.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there; you need to create (or retrieve from the service manager) a instance of `Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request`.

The difference is that this class will [use the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and set it within the constructor.](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/blob/master/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php#L242)

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
$method = $request->getMethod();
```

Comment: hey alex, how do i receive PUT and DELETE parameters in module.php zf2.

Comment: The request class doesn't seem to provided this. You can however retrive it using request body and parse the contents e.g `parse_str($request->getContent(), $data)` (where `$data` is populated with the `PUT` params)

Comment: Doing the same thing 

parse_str($request->getContent(), $data);
var_dump($data);
die;

but array results with 0 parameters but i am sending the 2 parameters. It should load in $data array. But not getting it.

Comment: Same code is working for DELETE method. but array resulting in length 0 for PUT request.